# Add a JS click event on a CoreUI element on .c-class-toggler

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events, core-ui

#### Question

How can I add an additional `click` event on a [CoreUI](https://coreui.io/docs/) element.

As far as my debugging goes, the main problem is that `CoreUI` a lot of `event.stopPropagation();` uses. This seems to destroy any further added `click` event.

#### Workaround

A hack I found was to comment out [line 2293 in the `coreui.js`](https://github.com/coreui/coreui/blob/v3.3.0/dist/js/coreui.js#L2293).

It's interesting, as this seams to be changed with Version 3.3.0. Even more confusing is, that version "3.2" (really 3.2.2) on [https://unpkg.com](https://unpkg.com/@coreui/coreui@3.2.2/dist/js/coreui.js) has already this changes (s. code snippet below).

#### Example

In the code snippet you can see that the menu opens/closes correctly but the *additional* `click` event doesn't get trigger.

[image: screenshot dev console event]

```js
$(document).ready(function () {   
    // Trigger when sidebar change, only works with hack of coreui.js
    $(document).on('click', '.c-class-toggler', function (event) {
        console.log('hello world!');
    });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/@coreui/coreui@3.2/dist/css/coreui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.perfect-scrollbar/1.5.0/css/perfect-scrollbar.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<body class="c-app">
<div id="sidebar" class="c-sidebar c-sidebar-fixed c-sidebar-lg-show">

    <div class="c-sidebar-brand d-md-down-none">
        <a class="c-sidebar-brand-full h4" href="#">
            Example
        </a>
    </div>

    <ul class="c-sidebar-nav ps m-4">
       <li class="c-sidebar-nav-item"><h3>Menu<h3></li>
    </ul>

</div>
<div id="app" class="c-wrapper">
    <header class="c-header c-header-fixed px-3">
        <button class="c-header-toggler c-class-toggler d-lg-none" type="button" data-target="#sidebar" data-class="c-sidebar-show">
            Menu
        </button> <pre class="ml-2 mt-4"><- additional click event is not working</pre>

        <button id="test" class="c-header-toggler c-class-toggler mfs-3 d-md-down-none" type="button" data-target="#sidebar" data-class="c-sidebar-lg-show" responsive="true">
            Menu
        </button>

        <ul class="c-header-nav ml-auto">

        </ul>
    </header>

    <div class="c-body">
        <main class="c-main">

            <div class="container-fluid">
                                                
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h2>Content</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

        </main>       
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.perfect-scrollbar/1.5.0/perfect-scrollbar.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@coreui/coreui@3.2/dist/js/coreui.min.js"></script>

</body>
```

*Note*: It seems like I'm not the only one with this issue: https://github.com/coreui/coreui/issues/155

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just run again over my question, the whole thing works also without my described hack.

**The trick is to hook on existing JS events.**

The debugger console normal show you the exciting events, eg. in case of the `sitebar` there is a `classtoggle` event you can hook on (s. example in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wittich/7xe3jypv/) or below).

[image: screenshot debugger console]

*One issue withe `coreui` is that the events have often different names to the normal bootstrap events.*

```js
$(document).ready(function () {   
    // Triggers when existing sidebar events are called
    $('#sidebar').on('classtoggle', function (event) {
        console.log('hello world!');
        $('.working').append('!');
    });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/@coreui/coreui@3.2/dist/css/coreui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.perfect-scrollbar/1.5.0/css/perfect-scrollbar.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<body class="c-app">
<div id="sidebar" class="c-sidebar c-sidebar-fixed c-sidebar-lg-show">

    <div class="c-sidebar-brand d-md-down-none">
        <a class="c-sidebar-brand-full h4" href="#">
            Example
        </a>
    </div>

    <ul class="c-sidebar-nav ps m-4">
       <li class="c-sidebar-nav-item"><h3>Menu<h3></li>
    </ul>

</div>
<div id="app" class="c-wrapper">
    <header class="c-header c-header-fixed px-3">

        <button id="test" class="c-header-toggler c-class-toggler mfs-3 d-md-down-none" type="button" data-target="#sidebar" data-class="c-sidebar-lg-show" responsive="true">            Menu
        </button>
    
        <button class="c-header-toggler c-class-toggler d-lg-none" type="button" data-target="#sidebar" data-class="c-sidebar-show">
            Menu
        </button> <pre class="working ml-2 mt-4"><- additional click event works when hooked to existing events</pre>

    </header>


    <div class="c-body">
        <main class="c-main">

            <div class="container-fluid">
                                                
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h2>Content</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

        </main>       
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.perfect-scrollbar/1.5.0/perfect-scrollbar.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@coreui/coreui@3.2/dist/js/coreui.min.js"></script>

</body>
```